# Как написать метод который будет редактировать(вписывать новую строку ппо столбцам) в эксель файле Pyton

Tags: python, pandas, excel

```
name          gender        dob           dod      age 

0 Данил       мужчина  1980-01-19       2019-02-16   NaN    
1  Владимир   мужчина  2002-12-24                    20.0    
2   Дмитрий   мужчина  001-11-04                     21.0    
3     Богдан  мужчина  2002-11-06                    NaN
```

```
def enter_data(self):
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    Df=pd.read_excel('.\Книга1')
    row=[]
    k=0
    a=input()
    for item in df[".\Книга1.xlsx"]:
        if re.search(item):
            row.append(k)
        k=k+1
```

у меня просто нет опыта работы в пандас и с питоном в экселе

Comment: Что нужно-то? Вывести фрейм в Excel? Используйте `df.to_excel()`

Comment: Надо чтобы вписывал в инпут строку например Александр мужчина 27.08.2002 20 лет и оно распределяло по столбцам

Comment: ну разбить ввод на части вы хотя бы можете?  и вообще, что у вас за каша вместо кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По описанию выходит так. Такой результат вы ожидаете?

```
import pandas as pd

rows = []
while True:
    a = input("Введите имя, пол, дата рождения, возраст через запятую: ")
    if len(a) == 0:
        break
    rows.append([x.strip() for x in a.split(',')])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.to_excel('out.xlsx')
```

```
Введите имя, пол, дата рождения, возраст через запятую: Александр, мужчина, 27.08.2002, 20 лет
Введите имя, пол, дата рождения, возраст через запятую: Александр, мужчина, 27.08.2002, 20 лет
Введите имя, пол, дата рождения, возраст через запятую: Александр, мужчина, 27.08.2002, 20 лет
Введите имя, пол, дата рождения, возраст через запятую:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!